# How to add on-change event (in mvc) with a distinct field id to multiple dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm fairly new to MVC.
I have a dialog with multiple rows, each containing two dropdownlists.
Row i contains a propertyOne dropdown list that sets the propertyOne property for field field id i.
So in the onchange event I want to know that field id i in order to know from which field I should set propertyOne.
The selection of PropertyOne affects the dropdown list items for PropertyTwo.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you in advance!

CorBins

---

Here's soms code (stripped down to the essentials).
First the view:

```
<table id="propertiestable">
@foreach (PropertyField field in Model.Fields)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayName(field.Id.ToString())</td>
        <td>Property 1:</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyOne, Model.ListItemsOne)                
        </td>
        <td>Property 2:</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyTwo, Model.ListItemsTwo)
        </td>
        <td>Property 3:</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertyThree)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeletePropClick(@field.Id)" value="X" name="RemoveProperty+@field.Id" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Model.Fields looks like this:

```
Public class PropertiesVM : EdgeActionBase {
    public List<PropertyField> Fields { get; set; }
..
```

}

```
public class PropertyField {
   public int Id { get; set: }
   public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
   public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
   public int PropertyThree { get; set; }
```

}

I'v tried something with JavaScript, but it don't work:

```
$('#@nameof(Model.Fields[i].PropertyOne)').on("change", function () {
alert('Hi there');
var selectedProperty = $(this).val();
var test = $(this).id();
var fields = '@Model.Fields';
let dataObj = { "Fields": fields, "PropertyOne": selectedProperty};
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SelectPropertyOnePartial")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            $("#divProperties").html(data);
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of this question, I think you want to get the index of current row when you select an options for `PropertyOne` property, So you can refer to this simple demo:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fields.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayName(Model.Fields[i].Id.ToString())</td>
        <td>Property 1:</td>
        <td>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Fields[i].PropertyOne,Model.ListItemsOne, "---Select Employee---", new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "Test(this)"} )
        </td>
        <td>Property 2:</td>
        //..........
        <br>
        
    </tr>
}

    <script>
        function Test(data){

              currentindex = data.name.substring(7, 8);
              var Id = parseInt(currentindex) + 1;
              alert("row index is :" + currentindex + "current row id is :" + Id)
            
        }
    </script>
```

Please note that the index of Fields start from 0, But the id of `PropertyField` start from 1, So if you want to get id, You need to `currentindex +1`.

Comment: Hi @CorBins, Have this answer helped you solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Xinran Shen,

Today I tried to apply your suggestion. And it worked!

Your answer helped me a lot!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Xinran Shen,

There is one problem though.
For example, if I have 3 rows and I select the fourth list item in the first row for PropertyOne, it turns out that the fourth list item is selected in all rows!
Do you have an idea how I can fix this?